# Where does the 60px margin come from?

Tags: html, css

When I check the following code in the *Chrome devtools* (device toolbar, responsive) and the window gets smaller than 1040px width, the ".wrapper" suddenly get's an increasing right margin until 60px.

I really can't understand why it get's this margin. Can anyone explain this behavior or push me in the right direction?

My HTML-/CSS-Code:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1040px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}

header[role="banner"] {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Headline</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything weird. .wrapper overflows body (which is by default 100% of the window size) because you specified an absolute width. Also, there's a negative margin right (margin: 0 auto) because of the overflow). What is that you are trying to accomplish? You didn't say in your original question.

Comment: You are establishing that the element **must** have a `1040px` width. If your screen is smaller that this, the element will overflow. Since you are setting the horizontal margin to `auto`, the negative margin is just compensating the difference between the viewport's width and the element's width

Answer (score 1):

The line "margin: 0 auto;"
actually means no vertical margin and spread the horizontal margin "automatically": That means there will be an equal margin on the left and right of your "wrapper" to fill in for what goes beyond the 1040 px.

Answer (score -1):

I am positive this is to do with the browser default style that is applied. Try using a normalize or css reset file with your code and see if the style is still applied.

Comment: Updated the answer for you.

Comment: Pretty sure that there is no default style that starts applying margin to elements after an arbitrary breakpoint.

Comment: Well as I said in my comment, I am positive ;)